# Spring + Apache CXF: SearchContextProvider not initialized

Tags: spring, jax-rs, cxf

I'm integrating Spring Boot with Apache CXF. Everyhthing is OK, but I cannot get the `SearchContext` to work inside the controllers:

```
@Context
private SearchContext context;

public @ResponseBody List<Users> getAll(@Context SearchContext context, @RequestParam String search){
    ....
}
```

The SearchContext is not correctly injected, as is not created by the `SearchContextProvider` in the package `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.search`.

I'm launching the CXF Servlet with this Bean:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean cxfServlet() {
    CXFServlet cxf = new CXFServlet();
    ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(cxf, "/api/*");
    return registration;
}
```

I'm using a Java-based configuration, no XML. 
In an XML based configuration, it seems that this tag is required:

```
<jaxrs:providers>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.search.SearchContextProvider"/>
</jaxrs:providers>
```

How can I declare the provider in a Java based configuration of the servlet?

Comment: And why should it? Wy should spring care about cxf annotations and classes... You are mixing 2 technologies that aren't designed to work together.

Comment: @m-denium From the spring official doc: _Jersey 1.x and Apache CXF work quite well out of the box if you just register their Servlet or Filter as a \@Bean in your application context_

Comment: Correct and I no where said that apache CXF won't work or that you can autowire Apache CXF web services. However you cannot use the types/annotations from apache CXF on spring controllers. That will not work.

Answer (score 0):

In your main config class, add:

```
@ComponentScan("org.apache.cxf.jaxrs")
```

Since the class (`SearchContextProvider`) is already annotated with `@Provider` annotation, Spring will be able to pick it up if it is being scanned. Assuming that you are already doing component-scan on your own package, you can just add the jaxrs package like:

```
@ComponentScan({ "com.something", "org.apache.cxf.jaxrs" })
```

Comment: Good hint, but I now get `Invoked method public abstract org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.search.SearchCondition org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.search.SearchContext.getCondition(java.lang.String,java.lang.Class) is no accessor method!`